# Use a custom component in pages

Tags: angular, ionic3

I've created a custom component with:

```
ionic generate component idioma
```

I did the same to create a page:

```
ionic generate component table
```

Now what I want to do is use my component idioma in my page table, here are the files that I'm using:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

import { IdiomaComponent } from '../components/idioma/idioma';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    IdiomaComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    IdiomaComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**idioma.ts**

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    /**
     * Generated class for the IdiomaComponent component.
     *
     * See https://angular.io/api/core/Component for more info on Angular
     * Components.
     */
    @Component({
      selector: 'idioma',
      templateUrl: 'idioma.html'
    })
    export class IdiomaComponent {

      text: string;

      constructor() {
        console.log('Hello IdiomaComponent Component');
        this.text = 'Hello World';
      }

    }
```

**components.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IdiomaComponent } from './idioma/idioma';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [IdiomaComponent],
    imports: [],
    exports: [IdiomaComponent]

})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

**table.html**

```
<!--
  Generated template for the MesaPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>table</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
<idioma></idioma>
</ion-content>
```

In the table.html I'm trying to use the component that I just created, but it's giving me this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'idioma' is not a known element:
1. If 'idioma' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

<ion-content padding>
  [ERROR ->]<idioma></idioma>
"): ng:///LoginPageModule/table.html@12:2
syntaxError@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:82661:34
TemplateParser.prototype.parse@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:93899:19
JitCompiler.prototype._compileTemplate@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:108093:18
JitCompiler.prototype._compileComponents/<@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:108012:56
JitCompiler.prototype._compileComponents@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:108012:9
JitCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents/<@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:107899:13
then@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:82650:143
JitCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:107898:16
JitCompiler.prototype.compileModuleAsync@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:107827:32
ModuleBoundCompiler.prototype.compileModuleAsync@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:108227:16
loadAndCompile/<@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:68163:16
M</l</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14354
onInvoke@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4247:24
M</l</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14281
M</c</r.prototype.run@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9504
f/<@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19620
M</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15029
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4238:24
M</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14942
M</c</r.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10195
o@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7267
M</h</e.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:16203
p@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:26991
v@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27238
```

The weird thing is that if I use the idioma component on my home page it does works, but if I use it elsewhere it doesn't, so I think I might be missing some import or export.

EDIT:
**table.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the TablePage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-table',
  templateUrl: 'table.html',
})
export class TablePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad MesaPage');
  }

}
```

**table.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TablePage } from './table';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TablePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(TablePage),
  ],
})
export class TablePageModule {}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of `table.ts`?

Comment: Yeah no problem

Comment: Restart your Ionic Serve, everything looks OK, I had this problem for hours. I think is a bug when it transpiles.

Comment: I just did it! But it's giving me the same error.

Comment: Can you show the `table.module.ts` file?

Comment: EDITED already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do this:

Remove all the `IdiomaComponent` related things from `app.module.ts`.It is not needed since it has its own module (i.e. `components.module.ts`).

After that import `ComponentsModule` as shown below.

*table.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TablePage } from './table';
import { ComponentsModule } from '../../components/components.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TablePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(TablePage),
    ComponentsModule //here
  ],
})
export class TablePageModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

As your IdiomaComponent is declared and exported from a separated ComponentsModule, you just have to import this module in the module where your intend to use it, here it's TablePageModule.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TablePage } from './table';
import { ComponentsModule } from '../../components/components.module';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TablePage,
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(TablePage),
  ],
})
export class TablePageModule {}
```

Comment: What is this components module?

Comment: ComponentsModule is the content of your components.module.ts file

Comment: It's seems that you intend to declare all your components in this file, separated from your app.module.ts file. This is a good practice, but you just missed to import it in your app module.

Comment: Now it's giving me this error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type TablePage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and TablePageModule! Please consider moving TablePage to a higher module that imports AppModule and TablePageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes TablePage then import that NgModule in AppModule and TablePageModule.

Comment: When you declare page or component in separate module, do not declare it again in AppModule! TablePageModule should appear in "import" section of AppModule, and remove every "TablePage" reference from AppModule

Comment: Ok, that was my bad ^^' But the error still the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157585/discussion-between-benjamin-caure-and-akaishu).